# action.setCallback(this, function(response) is not getting executed in Helper class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, helper, js

I have a weird behavior of Helper code in lightning component, where the control is not even entering inside action.setCallback, please suggest me if I am wrong:

JS Code:

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchAccRecord(component, event, helper, accId);
},
```

==============================================================================
Helper code:

```
fetchAccRecord : function(component,event,helper,accId) {
    if(!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(accId)) {
        var action = component.get('c.fetchStudyRec');
        action.setParams({
            'accIdVal' : accId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            alert('inside callback===>');
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);              
    }
},
```

===============================================================
Apex class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static CustomObject__c fetchAccRec(String accIdVal) {
    try{
        CustomObject__c accRec = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Id=:accIdVal];
        system.debug('accRec ===>'+accRec); //ABLE TO GET THE RESULTS IN THIS DEBUG
        return accRec;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex);
    }
}
```

MY POINT IS I AM Unable to get alert('inside callback===>') this alert on screen from helper once I execute doinit.

Answer (score 1):

In your called method `helper.fetchAccRecord(component, event, helper, accId);`
`accId` is undefined.

Your `accId` should contain some value.

That is why `!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(accId)` is failing and it is not entering the enqueaction.

And also your server side methodname `fetchAccRec` does not match client side caller method `component.get('c.fetchStudyRec');`.

**UPDATE**

If above fixes does not work, then try to show the debug logs, there are scenaris in which if the return data has some special characters then the payload fails inbetween. can you show what gets printed here.

`system.debug('accRec ===>'+accRec);`

If this gives some special characters then try to escape those and create a wrapper and pass the data through that.

Comment: the parameter which im passing already has value, and the control is going inside the apex class, and its giving me the results too, but later what ever is there in action.setCallback its not getting executed

Comment: But seeing the code above, how will `accId` would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a syntax error in your code The name of your action should match to the name of your apex method. This should be exactly similar!

It's easy to miss this because the name of the method on front end code is a simple string and there is no referential checks built into the system!

Looks like the names are not matching.

It should be `fetchStudyRec` in your controller method

Your backend apex method should be as below

```
@AuraEnabled
public static CustomObject__c fetchStudyRec(String accIdVal) { }
```

Double check that you are passing the right ID values to the backend method and it is not null or undefined

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, that has been taken care already, still its not working

Comment: Refresh the cache and give it a go! You can also find the component in the sources tab in chrome console and add debug points and trace the code! Also can you show how you are invoking the client side method?

Comment: Another thing to watch for is are there in errors on console